# AWS keeping services on domain instead of having public

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have hosted few services on AWS however all are public and can be accessed from anywhere which is a security threat, could you please let me know how to keep the services specific to internal users of organization without any authentication medium.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this, if you have list of IP range may be a network administrator can help you, take that and put them in load balancers under security group.

Answer (score -1):

You should spend some time reviewing security recommendations on AWS. Some excellent sources are:

- [Whitepaper: AWS Security Best Practices](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf)
- [AWS re:Invent 2017: Best Practices for Managing Security Operations on AWS (SID206) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjrcoK8T3To&feature=youtu.be)
- [AWS re:Invent 2017: Security Anti-Patterns: Mistakes to Avoid (FSV301) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzJmE_Jlas0)

AWS operates under a [[Shared Responsibility Model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/), which means that AWS provides many security tools and capabilities, but it is **your responsibility to use them correctly!**

Basic things you should understand are:

- Put public-facing resources in a **Public Subnet**. Everything else should go into a **Private Subnet**.
- Configure **Security Groups** to only open a minimum number of ports and IP ranges to the Internet.
- If you only want to open resources to "internal users of organization without any authentication medium", then you should connect your organization's network to AWS via [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) (private fiber connection) or via an **encrypted VPN connection**.

Security should be your first consideration in everything you put in the cloud — and, to be honest, everything you put in your own data center, too.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a LEAST PRIVILEGE approach when planning Network VPC Architecture, NACL and Firewall rules as well as IAM Access & S3 Buckets.

**LEAST PRIVILEGE:** Configure the minimum permission and Access required in IAM,Bucket Policies, VPC Subnets, Network ACL and Security Groups with a need to know White-list approach.

Start from having specific VPCs with **2 Main Segments** of Networks 1-**Public** and the other 2-**Private**.

- You will place your DMZ components on the **Public** segment,
  Components such as Internet Facing Web Server, load Balancers,
  Gateways, etc falls here.
- For the Rest such as Applications, Data, or Internal Facing
  LoadBalancers or WebServers make sure you place them in the Private
  Subnet where you will use an Internal IP address from specified
  Internal Range to refer to the Components Inside the VPC.
- If you have Multiple VPCs and you want them to talk with each
  other you can Peer them together.
- You also can use Route53 Internal DNS to simplify naming.
- Just in case, If you need to have Internet access from the Private segment
  you can Configure a NAT Gateway on the public subnet and handle
  Outgoing Traffic routed to Internet from the NAT Gateway.
- S3 Buckets can be Configured and Servered as VPC-END points. (Routing via an Internal Network rather than Internet Routed to S3 Buckets/Object).
- In IAM you can create Policies to whitelist source IP and attached to Roles and Users which is a great combination to Mix Network VPN Connections/white-listed IPs and keep Network Access in harmony with IAM. That means even Console Access could be governed by a White-listed Policy.

Comment: thanks is there any specific document/ link for this

Comment: Well not all of them in one place but I suggest you to start from Segmenting the VPC subnet and use NAT according to the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html